# iMacro - How to reduce default time(60 seconds) takes to search for an element when running a script?

Tags: python

I have developed more applications like form filling, multiple applications to be opened at a time etc, developed in such a way that the fields available in web application takes the input from CSV file as per mentioned in script.

I am focussing to develop iMacros for an application where it holds timesheet submission for multiple resources. I have developed an iMacro and the problem is that the time taken to complete the full process for a try is 2 min 30 seconds. Likewise, we need to run the scripts for multiple tries. When we go for QTP for the same process flow, it takes hardly around 40 sec for a try. I got stuck up where the user clicks on submit button, Once the macro code of clicking submit button is crossed, iMacro takes a minute to search for an element in next page,

Here a part of code is,

**TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:{ID Name} , \The code waits here for 60 seconds and it moves to next page and search for an element there and in next page, need to find the table elements. I feel that iMacro takes time (60 sec) to find the elements available in table format**

```
FRAME F=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:_idJsp4:udfs
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:_idJsp4 ATTR=ID:_idJsp4:dayAsRow:dayAsRowLines:0:regularHours CONTENT=9
```

I am in need of commands to reduce the time. It would be helpful if anyone knows the solution for it. Please help me to get out of this problem.

Note: I have tried in all my ways like inserting a code as SET !TIMEOUT_STEP, SET !TIMEOUT_TAG. None of these commands works as expected. I tried finding solutions for it through google and I came to know the concept of LOAD CHECK INTERVAL (By default, iMacro waits for 60 sec to search for an element).

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE X
```

and replace X with number of seconds you want. Default is 60. You can also change default waiting time in the Settings tab.